# Dynamic Struct with Dynamic Matrix

Tags: c, matrix, dynamic, struct

I'm having a little trouble doing a school project, and I can't post  all my code here because it might be copied by my schoolmates.

I have created a Dynamic Struct called Messages with the variable inside it `char ** phrases`, `int lines` (number of phrases at the moment), `int heaplines(max number of lines my char ** phrases can hold)`.

My program should work this way: it asks the user to insert messages, allocating memory to them and increasing the variable lines, which is the number of messages he has at the moment, if it reaches the max then I do an reallocation of +10 plus lines and it increases the heaplines. But my true problem is I cant allocate memory to the string the user has inserted because it gives me an error saying:

```
Incompatible Pointers types "char **" and "char *"
```

.

```
MSG->phrases=(char*)malloc((tamphrase+1)*sizeof(char));
```

Allocating the lines for the matrix of `char ** msg` it works perfectly, but when I try to allocate memory for the string that is going to be inserted it gives me that error on that line of code above.

Btw, how can I increment the lines of the matrix of phrases?
For example:

```
MSG->(phrases+i)=(char*)malloc((tamphrase+1)*sizeof(char));
```

(I know this is wrong, but I hope you guys know what I'm trying to say)

Comment: Please post your code. It's the only way to have an answer

Answer (score 1):

`MSG->phrases=(char*)malloc((tamphrase+1)*sizeof(char));` is a `char**` so allocating memory to it would be

```
MSG->phrases=malloc((tamphrase+1)*sizeof(char*));
```

Well then for each of the `tamphrase` you allocate memory for holding characters.

```
MSG->phrases[i]=malloc((MAXLENOFLINE+1)*sizeof(char));
```

Also you should read about `realloc` to get an idea about the reallocating when you run out of already allocated memory in your code.

Don't cast the return value of `malloc`, it's unnecessary and doing so may suppress error in case error occurs.

---

If you understand the logic of pointers a bit then you wouldn't have problem writing these lines.

you said `phrases` are `char**`. Now think what a `char**` holds. It holds the address of `char*` variables. Now you will allocate a chunk of memory each capable of holding `char*` variables and then you return the starting address of it to `phrases`.

Now same way you think the other way, `char*` holds the address of a `char` variable. You will allocate a memory where you will store the `char` variables. You return the starting address to the `char*` variables.
`phrases[i]` holds that.

---

Without going into detail, the general structure of the code will be something like this

```
MSG->phrases=malloc((tamphrase+1)*sizeof(char*));
if( MSG->phrases == NULL ){
    fprintf(stderr,"Error in malloc");
    exit(1);
} 
for(size_t i = 0; i < tamphrase+1; i++ ){
    MSG->phrases[i]=malloc((MAX_LINE_LENGTH+1)*sizeof(char));
    if( MSG->phrases[i] == NULL ){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error in malloc");
        exit(1);
    }     
}
...
...
// do cool stuff
..
..

//free the allocated memory
for(size_t i = 0; i < tamphrase+1; i++ ){
    free(MSG->phrases[i]);
}
free(MSG->phrases);
```